# When taking an element from an array in an object, does Java have to read the whole array?

Tags: java, performance

For example given the following methods:

```
    public double[] getCoord(){
        return coord;
}

    public double getCoord(int variable){
        return coord[variable];
}
```

Would it be better to call

```
object.getCoord()[1]
```

or

```
object.getCoord(1)
```

and why?

Comment: Your first call should presumably read object.getCoord()[1] rather than object.getCoord[1].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there is no performance difference, the second method presents a far superior API, because Java arrays are always *mutable*. The first API lets your users write

```
object.getCoord()[1] = 12.345;
```

and modify internals of your object behind your back. This is never a good thing: even a non-malicious users could do things you never intended, simply by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, it doesn't matter. The first method returns a reference to the array, not a copy.

That said, the second method protects the array from being modified outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't read the whole array when you use the subscript operator (`[]`).  With regards to would it be better to use the accessor method to grab the array first, then index into it versus call a method that does the same thing, it's probably negligible.  You're still incurring the overhead (minimal mind you) of invoking a function and returning a result either way.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that #2 is marginally slower because a parameter has to be pushed onto the stack prior to the call to getCoord(int).  Not much in it though.

Neither has to read the whole array.

Both are slower than direct array access, for example coord[1].